# Why Doesn't Haskell Generalize Some Functions

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following in a file:

```
import Control.Monad
ema a = scanl1 $ \m n -> (1-a)*m + a*n
macd  = ema 9 . uncurry (zipWith (-)) . liftM2 (,) (ema 26) (ema 12)
```

On compile, I get the following:

```
:t macd
macd :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

However,

```
:t ema 9 . uncurry (zipWith (-)) . liftM2 (,) (ema 26) (ema 12)
ema 9 . uncurry (zipWith (-)) . liftM2 (,) (ema 26) (ema 12)
  :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
```

So, why the difference in the more restricted type for `macd`?

Answer (score 10):

This is the monomorphism restriction.

The gist is that when you have a constrained type variable, Haskell won't generalize if it's bound to a single identifier

```
f = term
```

However if it's a function binding, eg

```
f a ... = term
```

Then it is generalized. I've answered this question enough that I wrote up a more complete example in a [blog post](http://www.dannygratzer.com/2013/07/the-monomorphism-restriction.html)

---

As for why we have the monomorphism restriction,

```
-- let's say comp has the type [Num a => a]
foo = (comp, comp)
  where comp = super_expensive_computation
```

How many times would `comp` be computed? If we infer general types automatically it could compute it twice. But this might surprise you if you wrote something like this intending to have the type `Num a => (a, a)` or similar.

The extra computation occurs because in Core land something like

```
foo :: Num a => a
```

turns into something more like

```
 foo :: NumDict -> a -- NumDict has the appropriate functions for + - etc
                     -- for our a
```

A function. Since `foo`s general type is `(Num a, Num b) => (a, b)` unless GHC can prove that the `NumDict`s that `comp` is getting in both cases are the same, it can't share the result of `comp`

Comment: As a meta note, there really ought to be a definitive "here's what the monomorphism restriction is" question that we can link to here

Comment: I see. Thanks. The easy way to fix this then is `ema a xs = scanl1 (\m n -> (1-a)*m + a*n) xs` and `macd xs = ema 9 . uncurry (zipWith (-)) . liftM2 (,) (ema 26) (ema 12) $ xs`

Comment: @me2 Yep, or just add type signatures :) Usually that's what I'd recommend. It's helpful for humans and compilers

Comment: @me2 Jozefg mentioned that `Num a => a` gets turned in to `NumDict -> a`, if you want to know precisely how this is implemented I would suggest this great talk http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/MDCC-TechTalk-Classes-Jim-but-not-as-we-know-them.  It's very approachable, you don't need much haskell knowledge to follow along, and by the end of it you'll discover how typeclasses are really just pretty syntax for pure data types.